# Pixel colour intensity

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

This collage is what im supposed to get....
[image: Target image]

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
from PIL import ImageDraw

# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')

# build a list of 9 images which have different brightnesses
enhancer=ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
images=[]
for i in range(1, 10):
    images.append(enhancer.enhance(i/10))

# create a contact sheet from different brightnesses
first_image=images[0]
contact_sheet=PIL.Image.new(first_image.mode, (first_image.width*3,first_image.height*3))
x=0
y=0

for img in images:
    # Lets paste the current image into the contact sheet
    contact_sheet.paste(img, (x, y) )
    # Now we update our X position. If it is going to be the width of the image, then we set it to 0
    # and update Y as well to point to the next "line" of the contact sheet.
    if x+first_image.width == contact_sheet.width:
        x=0
        y=y+first_image.height
    else:
        x=x+first_image.width

# resize and display the contact sheet
contact_sheet = contact_sheet.resize((int(contact_sheet.width/2),int(contact_sheet.height/2) ))
display(contact_sheet)
```

This is what i get....
[image: Final Image]
The above code just varies brightness....

Also, the text doesnt appear at bottom as it should....

Please tell me what changes should i make to vary color intensity in this code and text problem as well
.....
Please help and point out the changes in this code ... Appreciated!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change image color in PIL module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184160/change-image-color-in-pil-module)

Comment: No, this is different, nevertheless thanks for suggesting it...

Comment: The code is identical to your other question. Please don't ask the same question twice, it wastes people's time. Instead, you should edit your original question and delete this one.